# Entropy and Gini - difference in distributions

Tags: statistics, information-theory

Are there any two distributions X and Y such that entropy of X is greater than entropy of Y but Gini impurity of X is smaller than Gini impurity of Y. Is there any relation between entropy and gini impurity?